# Website and Native app user authorization

Tags: authorization, cross-platform, native

I wish to create a functionality that is very similar to facebook or pokerstars if you have used them before. Basically the apps require the user to login and their information can be accessed from both browsers and native and web apps.

How can I go about achieving this? Please advice on what services to research on to accomplish this. To my current understanding. I would be creating the website in html and php and creating a webservice using RESTful protocols and hosting them on amazon aws servers. I can then connect to these servers in the native apps? I am not very clear on how the native apps will interact with the servers

If you know of any particular protocol or a better server hosting service please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you are looking for something like this:

1. The user starts either your browser app or your native app (perhaps a mobile app)
2. Since the user does not have an account yet, you present them with the appropriate dialog to create said account.
3. You then ask the "Identity Service" to create a profile for that user
4. The identity service returns a token for access

This is something we do in the mobile network industry all the time.  Technically, we have TAC/ACS or HSS profile services, but in either case, it's the same thing -- a dedicated service and network process that:

1. Accepts connections from various clients (web, mobile, desktop...)
2. Has various primitives along the database CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) model
3. Answers requests the database

If you want a pre-configured solution, you could just use any networked database with a RESTstyle connector for example (MongoDB maybe?)  But you could also just through this in a process that talks to a NoSQL or SQLLite database.   The end result is the same.

For commercial solutions, I might like at OpenStack as you can run your code on it and they have identity brokers you might be able to CoOpt.

Personally, I'd just have a datastore running on a cloud somewhere like Amazon's EC2 which answers RESTful requests such as:

- Create a user with a given profile set, return a unique token
- Delete a user given a token
- Update elements of the profile for a given token

I'm leaving out the necessary things like security here, but you get the idea.

This also has the advantage that you can have a single identity service for all of your applications/application services.  The specifics for a given application element are just sub-fields in the profile.   This gives you, not only a common identity broker for web, desktop and mobile, but a single-sign-on for all your applications.  The user signs in once and is authenticated for everything you have.  Moving from site to site, now just became seamless.

Lastly, you place your identity management, backup, security token management, etc OUTSIDE of your application.  If you later want to add Google Authenticator for second-factor authentication, you don't have to add it to every application you have.

I should also add that you don't want to keep the identity database on the direct internet connection point.   Someone could make your life difficult and get ahold it later on.   Rather, you want your identity server to have a private link to it.   Then do something like this:

- When the account is created, don't store passwords, store hashes -- much safer
- Have your application (web or otherwise) compute a key as the login

In this case, the user might enter a username and password, but the application or website would convert it into a token.  THAT is what you send across.

- Next, using that token (and suitable security magic), use THAT as the owner key
- Send that key to the datastore and retrieve any needed values
- Encrypt them back into a blob with the token
- Send the block
- THe application decrypts the blob to get at values

Why do we do this?

First, if someone were to try to get at your identity database, there's nothing useful.  It contains only opaque tokens for logins, and blobs of encrypted data.   Go ahead -- take the database.  We don't care.

Second, sniffing the transport gets an attacker nothing -- again, it's all encrypted blobs.

This means later on, when you have five applications using the broker, and someone hacks the network and steals the database, you don't care, because your users never gave out logins and passwords in the first place, and even if they did, the data itself is garbage to anyone without the user key.

Does this help?

Comment: That is just amazing information. I will start exploring right away. Thanks alot.